# Why is it that I cannot deploy my otherwise working Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, deployment, wcf-ria-services

Inside of Visual Studio my Silverlight Business Application works fine. But when I publish it to my local machine's IIS (version 6.1), it runs fine, but doesn't seem to be able to access the RIA services.  The first error to pop up is:

[image]

The application otherwise works fine.  It navigates fine.  That is, until it tries to access data from the server through RIA services.  I get messages like:

[image]

I know very little about deploying web applications, let alone silverlight applications with RIA services.  I published using the following settings:

[image]

**Edit:**

I've used fiddler to get the exact error after realizing that the "NotFound" exception could be anything.  It is as follows.

---

### Server Error in '/PPCa' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested URL:** /PPCa/login.aspx

---

I don't have a login.aspx page.  Is this something internal to Silverlight?  Do I need to create such a page?

Comment: What identity is in the appPool for you application? Does that identity have permissions to your database?

Comment: @Rus, My appPool id is "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: Have you tried to type in the URL to one of your RIA domain services directly into IE? They will look something like http://youhost/DomainServiceNameSpace-Web-FooDomainService.svc. If you get back a service config page then RIA is functioning serverside ok.

Comment: @Rus, I get the same error that is listed above in the edit. ^  I looked and I don't have a MIME type registered for .svc is this necessary?

Comment: Have you registered WCF with IIS? Have a look at the article if you haven't http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

Comment: @Rus, I followed the link, but its for WCF version 3.0.  I'm using version 4.0 I believe.  I have no idea if I've registered WCF with IIS.  How does one do this?  How does one know if its done?

Comment: WCF was added in v3 of DotNet. If you look in c:\windows\Microsoft.net\v3\windows communication framework or one of it's sub directories the file servicemodelreg.exe it is this app when run with -I flag that will register wcf with iis. You can tell if it works by looking at the list of mime types registered you will see .svc there.

Comment: @Rus, I've run that command.  It completed successfully, but my MIME types still don't contain that entry.  And you should clarify that that is a capital i, it looks like an l.

Comment: Sorry about that. I would restart IIS and then see if a request to http://yourhost/DomainServiceNameSpace-Web-FooDomainService.svc works now.

Comment: @Rus, I've tried restarting IIS, and even windows itself.  Still no .svc entry in the MIME types.  I've even tried running ServiceModelReg again.  Nothing.  Can I put the entry in manually?

Comment: Did you run the serviceModelReg.exe as an administrator?

Comment: @Rus, yes, I ran it in an elevated console.  It gives me an error otherwise. Also, now when I try to access my service it gives me a 404 on Login.aspx.  I still don't understand that as I don't have a Login.aspx or a reference to one. Does this have something to do with the config defaulting to forms auth?

Comment: Just to check - what OS are you running on?

Comment: Also, ensure your web config has this in for now <system.web>

   <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, I'm using my development computer for testing.  Makes iterative deployment much simpler.  So I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7 you will be using IIS7.

In Internet Information Services Manager application (found in administrative tools) click the top most node in the left hand pane which will look something like MACHINENAME (MACHINENAME\yourUsername). In the list of features double click the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions and ensure that the ASP.NET versions shown are allowed and not denied.

To prove that WCF has been registered with IIS check in the list of features for the Modules icon, double click it and look through the list for ServiceModel-4.0.

The web.config of your web project that hosts your Silverlight XAP should look like this (plus extras like your DB connection strings etc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
           type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I have verified all of that stuff.  I don't have ISAPU, I have ISAPI.  No luck. :(  Also, I don't know if it matters, but I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows 7.

Comment: I figured it out.  Well, I don't really understand why, but I moved the web target out of the \inetpub\wwwroot folder into another folder and it worked.  I also connected as myself instead of the Application user.  Don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at this:

- [How to delpoy RIA services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bradsevertson/archive/2011/02/17/a-guide-to-deploying-ria-services-solutions.aspx)
  and this
- [SL and RIA issue](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/119726/327375.aspx)

Comment: Can you explain *why* these links would be useful. That would make this an answer worthy of acceptance.

Comment: @Aswin, Yeah sorry, I usually ignore link answers.  If you don't know,  and can't help, don't answer.

Comment: @Jordan.. Well.. You said you know very little about deploying web applications. The first link tells you how to  deploy RIA services and the second one talks about issues while publishing SL RIA app.

Comment: @Aswin, Thank you, that's all I'm asking for is some context. Add that to your answer, and I'll remove the -1.

Comment: While using Fiddler, instead of localhost, use 127.0.0.1.:<PortNumber>. And download and install this. WCF Binary Inspector: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfbinaryinspector This should take you few steps towards your solution. PS: Sorry about the link. No use in copy pasting stuff if it is existing somewhere already.

Comment: Yes there is every use in summarising what exists elsewhere. While these links are to MSDN pages sites have been known to go dark and these pages may get moved. Without context these links will become useless.